# What relationship choose for 2 tables

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA(hibernate) and faced with problem. I have 2 entities. 1 is a '*Planes*' and the second one is '*Air-port*'. What I am creating now is a search web application, and I am trying to prepare all parts for it. So User needs to search 'planes' by 'Air-port', so it is '***OneToMany***' relationship.
But the problem is, that If I make it 'OneToMany' for example like this:

**Planes entity**

```
 //...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy='plane')
    private Set<Planes> planes = new HashSet<Planes>();
    //...
```

and accordingly to this,
**Air-port entity**

```
//...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="AirPort_ID")
private Planes plane;
```

But It does not fit, because in this situation, a plane has only 1 air-port. This is not true. So, when User hits an Air-port ID, it will select all planes in it. But still, each plane will have only 1 Air-Port. ***So, to solve this, maybe it will be more better to use ManyToMany?*** That Airport can have many planes, and plane can have many airports.

Comment: Why don't you make a new entity to represent a flight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ask yourself what the relationship between `Plane` and `Airport` actually represents.  I can think of a number of possibilities.

- This airport owns this plane.
- This plane is currently on the ground at this airport.
- This plane is currently en route to this airport.
- This plane is permitted to use this airport.

Which of these are you going to represent in your database?  It seems to me that three of these relationships are one-to-many, and one of them is many-to-many.  So you need to decide what relationship you're trying to represent, before you decide its cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

Many to many relationship would be the right way to go in this situation since an airport can have many airplanes and an airplane many airports

Comment: having a one to many relationship will give you problems in this case unless the airplane stays at its airport or that airport has only that one airplane